# NTLM Auth via Apex

Tags: apex, integration, webservices, authentication

I'm trying to make a service that calls an external system using the NTLM auth.

I thought that it should be very likely the BASIC auth - but perhaps I'm wrong.

I'd like to know the right way to auth via this way.

What I did so far is :

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http h = new Http();

req.setEndpoint('https://someURL');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setTimeout(120000);
String username = 'Username';
String password = 'passwod'; 

Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'NTLM ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);            

res = h.send(req);

System.debug(res);
System.debug(req);
```

But I'm getting Unauthorized from the external system, while from POSTMAN its works as expected.

Postman :

[image]

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you also share the postman screen shot ? With `Authorization` pair, just hide the value and show what does it starts with? and what headers are you firing postman with?

Comment: @NagendraSingh Hope it's what you meant.

thanks!

Comment: Yeah, try not using the `Authorization` tab and direclty putting the `Authorization` header in Headers from header tab. Check if that works.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Not sure how to do it...
I opened the Headers tab and added the "Authorization" as the key.
 in which way should I add the user name and password at the value section?

Comment: That would be normal username:password with whatever suffix you use , I see you have used `NTLM `

Comment: @NagendraSingh Unauthorized result..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116775/discussion-between-salvation-and-nagendra-singh).

Comment: So I was checking if the same when passed as header, will that ever work or not, so for `NTLM' from apex you have to follow this : http://atulrsfdc.blogspot.com/2015/09/using-ntlm-authentication-from.html`, you cannot do `NTLM` authentication via headers I believe.

Comment: Hi @identigral, I saw this post.
I thought that writing service with NTLM is like the same approach -  a BASIC auth, with username and Password...
Thanks. I'll try to implement it.